# Sticky forms in php

Tags: php, forms, sticky

My code:

```
<label>Year: </label>
    <?php
        print '<select>';
        $start_year = date('1910');
        for ($y = $start_year; $y <= ($start_year + 104); $y++) {
            print "<option value=\"$y\">$y</option>";
        }

        print '</select>';
    ?>
```

and our professor wants us to incorporate it being sticky with something like a code like this:

```
echo "<option value=\"$option\"";

            if ($messageType == $option){
                //make it sticky
                echo ' selected="selected"';
            }

            echo ">$option</option>";
```

however that code isn't working with my code and i can't seem for it to become a default value/sticky.

Comment: I think you should be asking your professor for help with this one. But looking at your code, where do you set the value of `$messageType`?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert that's a different value for him. But he wanted us to incorporate the echo ' selected="selected"';

Answer (score 1):

In your **for loop**:

```
for ($y = $start_year; $y <= ($start_year + 104); $y++) {
     ($y== $option) ? echo '<option value="'.$y.'" selected="selected">'.$y.'</option>' : echo '<option value="'.$y.'">'.$y.'</option>';
}
```

I assumed that the value of `$option` is a **year** available in your **for loop**.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to post an entire answer for this but i cannot comment yet... Given your problem "can't seem for it to become a default value" My money on its a very simple issue

```
echo ' selected="selected"';
```

should just be

```
echo ' selected';
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

but view source on the webpage it generates and make sure the HTML is generating as expected otherwise